# why my python loop returns only the final round result

Tags: python

I am trying to do the [Random Quiz Generator](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/) in Automate the Boring Stuff. The project requires to write a python program to generate 35 quiz files and 35 answer files. Each quiz file will have 50 multiple-choice questions in random order.

I have not finished the answer files yet, but I finished most of the quiz file coding. My problem:
In each quiz file, instead of 50 questions, I only have one question, "Question 50".

I think the loop has a problem but I don't know where I got wrong... Below is my code. Thank you for your help.

```
import os, random

capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver', 'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee', 'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois': 'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas': 'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine': 'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan': 'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri': 'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada': 'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh', 'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City', 'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence', 'South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee': 'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont': 'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}


states = list(capitals.keys())

for quizNum in range(35):
    quizFile = open(f"Capital_Quiz{quizNum+1}.txt",'w')
    answerFile = open(f"Capital_Quiz_answer{quizNum+1}", 'w')
    
    # Write out the header for the quiz.
    quizFile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n') 
    quizFile.write((' ' * 20) + f"State Capitals Quiz (Form {quizNum+1})") 
    quizFile.write('\n\n')
    
    random.shuffle(states)
    
    for questionNum in range(50):
        correct_answer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
        wrong_answer = list(capitals.values())
        wrong_answer.remove(correct_answer)
        wrong_answer = random.sample(wrong_answer, 3)
        answer_option = wrong_answer + [correct_answer]
        random.shuffle(answer_option)
    
        quizFile.write(f"{questionNum + 1}. What is the capital of {states[questionNum]}?\n")
        for i in range(4):
            quizFile.write(f"{'ABCD'[i]}. {answer_option[i]}\n")
        quizFile.write("\n")
        quizFile.close()
```

Comment: You're calling `quizFile.close()` in the wrong place.

Comment: Move quizFile.close() out of the second loop

Comment: Also, it's strange to me that you are getting question 50 - I would have expected it to write question 1 then fail with an I/O error for writing to a closed file

Comment: Consider using a `with` statement to avoid needing to manually close your files at the right time (and not too early or too late).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help (´▽`ʃ♡ƪ)  now it works~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at your last line:

```
quizFile.close()
```

You are closing the file everytime you write a question, so the 2nd question will overwrite the 1st question etc. which explains why in the end you only have 50th question.

To solve this you can simply decrease indentation of `quizfile.close()` so that it aligns with `quizfile = open ...`. I.e. you don't close the file every time per question, you only close it after writing all 50 questions

Comment: Thank you Mr. K for your help (´▽`ʃ♡ƪ)  now it works~

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the file at wrong place.

```
import os, random

capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver', 'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee', 'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois': 'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas': 'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine': 'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan': 'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri': 'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada': 'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh', 'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City', 'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence', 'South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee': 'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont': 'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}


states = list(capitals.keys())

for quizNum in range(35):
    quizFile = open(f"Capital_Quiz{quizNum+1}.txt",'w')
    answerFile = open(f"Capital_Quiz_answer{quizNum+1}", 'w')

    # Write out the header for the quiz.
    quizFile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n') 
    quizFile.write((' ' * 20) + f"State Capitals Quiz (Form {quizNum+1})") 
    quizFile.write('\n\n')

    random.shuffle(states)

    for questionNum in range(50):
        correct_answer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
        wrong_answer = list(capitals.values())
        wrong_answer.remove(correct_answer)
        wrong_answer = random.sample(wrong_answer, 3)
        answer_option = wrong_answer + [correct_answer]
        random.shuffle(answer_option)

        quizFile.write(f"{questionNum + 1}. What is the capital of {states[questionNum]}?\n")
        for i in range(4):
            quizFile.write(f"{'ABCD'[i]}. {answer_option[i]}\n")
        quizFile.write("\n")
    quizFile.close() # This should be in outer for loop
```

Also you are not writing the answer to `answerFile`

Comment: Thank you MjZac for your help (´▽`ʃ♡ƪ)  now it works~